# Get file size in javascript for multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery Form Plugin to upload my files via AJAX and I also want to check if size is more than 20mb on every file before I send them to server. I've discovered [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) HTML5 example, but I can't figure out how to put it together with my code here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-videos').ajaxForm({
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        beforeSubmit : function(){
            var fileInput = $('.form-videos :input[type=file]');
            var totalFiles = $('.form-videos :input[type=file]').get(0).files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++)
            {
                alert('what?'); // This works and prints out correctly for every file
                // How do I get current file size?
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to;

```
var files = $('.form-videos :input[type=file]').get(0).files;
for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
   if (files[i].size > 20971520) ...
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us how to do the same thing in IE ?

Comment: Hope it can help somebody https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663160/jquery-validate-filesize-in-multidimensional-array-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

See an example [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

In your example, `length` is simply the number of selected files. You need to access the individual `File` objects and their `size` property.