# JQuery Validate Filesize in Multidimensional Array Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I tried using jquery validate but i've spent more than 4 hours to search how to solve my problem but couldn't find it. The problem is when I tried using jquery validate for filesize in multidimensional array, it doesn't work. It can still submit the form and not showing the error message.

Here is it my field

```
var numberIncr = 1;
        $('#add-berkas').click(function () {
            var box_html = $('<div class="text-box form-group row">\n' +
                '                        <div class="col-sm-8">\n' +
                '                            <input type="text" name="berkas['+numberIncr+'][nama]" placeholder="Nama File" class="form-control" required>\n' +
                '                        </div>\n' +
                '                        <div class="col-sm-4">\n' +
                '                            <input type="file" name="berkas['+numberIncr+'][file]" id="berkasfile'+numberIncr+'" accept="application/pdf" required/>\n' +
                '                            <button id="remove-berkas" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger remove-box" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>\n' +
                '                        </div>\n' +
                '                    </div>');
            $('.text-box:last').after(box_html);
            box_html.fadeIn('slow');
            numberIncr++;
        });
```

And this is the validate

```
        $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function (value, element, param) {
            return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
        }, 'File size must be less than {0}');

        var berkas = $('input[name^="berkas"]');
        berkas.filter('input[name$="[file]"]').each(function() {
            $(this).rules("add", {
                extension: "pdf", filesize:1048576,
                messages: "Berkas must be PDF and less than 1MB"
            });
        });

        $("#form").validate({
            rules: {
                surat: {extension: "pdf", filesize: 1048576, },
            },
            messages: {
                surat: "Surat must be PDF and less than 1MB",
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error,element){
                showErrorMessage(error.text());
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is not good enough.  Please edit the question to clearly describe the issue as well as any troubleshooting steps.  Did you look at the DOM?  What part is not working?

Comment: I still can submit the form, while filesize more than 1 MB @Sparky

Comment: Did you do any troubleshooting?  Did you examine your DOM?  Why have you not shown us your HTML markup?  Does your custom validation work when it's not a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by presumably only calling this code once on page load, when the fields don't yet exist...

```
berkas.filter('input[name$="[file]"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        extension: "pdf", filesize:1048576,
        messages: "Berkas must be PDF and less than 1MB"
    });
});
```

There are no matching fields at the time you call this code. The whole point of this method is for you to *dynamically* add the rules ***after*** you create each field.

You must call it immediately after adding a new field.  Put it inside the `click` handler near the bottom.

```
var numberIncr = 1;
$('#add-berkas').click(function () {
    var box_html = $('<div class="text-box form-group row">\n' +
        .....
        '                    </div>');
    $('.text-box:last').after(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');

    // add rules to new field here
    $('[name="berkas[' + numberIncr + '][file]"]').rules("add", {
        extension: "pdf", filesize:1048576,
        messages: "Berkas must be PDF and less than 1MB"
    });
    
    numberIncr++;
});
```

You wouldn't need an `.each()` since you only create one field on each click.  Just target the new field and add the rule.

Comment: aa i see. because i add it dynamically so the rules should be added dynamically too. Thanks a lot, it works!